# StringBuffer vs StringBuilder

Tags: java, algorithm, stringbuilder, synchronized, stringbuffer

I am taking Algorithms implementation class. And my teacher mentioned StringBuffer and StringBuilder, he said StringBuffer is safer than StringBuilder because in terms of threading. Is that true? And if so, what does that mean? I've looked up this question and lots of the answers mentioned synchronizing. Can anyone explain what that means and how does that make StringBuffer safer than StringBuilder?

Comment: See [What is thread safe in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6324085/4125191)

Comment: Also note that this doesn't mean you should prefer using `StringBuffer` to `StringBuilder`. Quite the contrary - whenever you use it locally, in a single thread, always prefer `StringBuilder`. Use `StringBuffer` only where you need to share the string-building object between threads.

Comment: You almost never need the "extra safety" of `StringBuffer`, and it just incurs extra performance cost with no benefit.

Answer (score 5):

`StringBuffer` has all methods synchronized.

From [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html):

> A thread-safe, mutable sequence of characters

Synchronization is a system to synchronize thread access to portion of code so that at most one thread can execute a synchronized block.

If your code is not multithreading or simply if the `StringBuffer` you are using is not shared between threads use `StringBuilder`. It is faster.

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) of StringBuilder:

> A mutable sequence of characters. This class provides an API
>   compatible with StringBuffer, but with **no guarantee of**
>   **synchronization**. This class **is designed for use as a drop-in**
>   **replacement for StringBuffer in places where the string buffer was**
>   **being used by a single thread (as is generally the case)**. Where
>   possible, **it is recommended that this class be used in preference to**
>   **StringBuffer as it will be faster** under most implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of its methods are synchronized, it means that even if you have 100 threads (or more) using and modifying it at the same time, it will perform each operation fully before handling other requests. With a StringBuilder you have no such guarantees.