# Synchronization of methods of differents classes

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I have two classes each with one method.

```
class A {
    private void insert(String usedId){
        // ...
    }
}

class B {
    private void refresh(String userId){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Each method is called from a different `Thread`. They are called from different `Thread`s for different `userId`s.

I need to lock the first method when second is called and vise versa for the same `userId`.

Is the best choice to hold a `List` of ids and set the lock?

Comment: No. Best choice to to specify your use case not specify what you want to do. This sounds a lot like an XY problem. For example - if both methods update a map the the map can be made threadsafe, etc. Take a step back - what is your use case?

Comment: There are ways of doing this, but first I'd probably question why two seemingly independent classes need to lock the same resource.

Comment: I have API call modification of user and API call of periodic update. I need to serialize calls when are called at same time and add delay between modification and periodic update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We introduce a `LockDispenser`. You pass this object to all `A`s and `B`s you want to have [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6324145/4298200). It will provide `Lock` objects with `createLock(String forId)` which need to be released after use by calling `releaseLock(String forId)`.

```
public class LockDispenser {
    private final Map<String, Lock> dispenser = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Object createLock(String forId) {
        synchronized (dispenser) {
            if (!dispenser.containsKey(forId)) {
                dispenser.put(forId, new Lock());
            }
            Lock lock = dispenser.get(forId);
            lock.referenceCounter++;
            return lock;
        }
    }

    public void releaseLock(String forId) {
        synchronized (dispenser) {
            Lock lock = dispenser.get(forId);
            lock.referenceCounter--;
            if (lock.referenceCounter == 0) {
                dispenser.remove(forId);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Lock {
        private int referenceCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

---

Now the actual thread safety comes from using the `Lock` in a [`synchronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) block.

```
public class  A {
    private LockDispenser dispenser;

    public A(LockDispenser dispenser) {
        this.dispenser = dispenser;
    }

    private void insert(String userId) {
        synchronized (dispenser.createLock(userId)) {
            // code
        }
        dispenser.releaseLock(userId); // consider putting this in a finally block
    }
}
```

---

```
public class B {
    private LockDispenser dispenser;

    public B(LockDispenser dispenser) {
        this.dispenser = dispenser;
    }

    private void refresh(String userId) {
        synchronized (dispenser.createLock(userId)) {
            // code
        }
        dispenser.releaseLock(userId); // consider putting this in a finally block
    }
}
```

Make sure `releaseLock(String forId)` is called even if an Exception is thrown. You can do this by putting it into a [`finally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) block.

And create them like such:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    LockDispenser fooLock = new LockDispenser();
    A fooA = new A(fooLock);
    B fooB = new B(fooLock);


    LockDispenser barLock = new LockDispenser();
    A barA = new A(barLock);
    B barB = new B(barLock);
}
```

`fooA` and `fooB` are thread safe with each other and so are `barA` and `barB`.

Comment: You are going to need to use `finally` to release the locks, otherwise when errors occur then locks will be left dangling.

Comment: 1. What is `lock.referenceCounter`? I reckon you're not referring to `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`, which you should be as there's no particular reason to reinvent the wheel in this case 2. Why not use `ConcurrentHashMap.merge` instead of synchronizing on a non thread-safe map?