# setContentView causes IllegalStateException

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I'm having a crash report from exactly one user who's device SM-G360H that is using android API 19 and it's occurrence is very rare. I don't even know how to reproduce the issue.

My code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    // Other code
}
```

And for my XML :

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/mydrawable"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/rightView"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/rightView"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>
<!-- other views -->
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/viewHeight"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/my_custome_behaviour"/>
```

The exception is thrown at `setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);`

Here is my stack trace:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: State: FLUSHED
java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.illegalStateException (CharsetEncoder.java:670)
java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode (CharsetEncoder.java:360)
java.io.OutputStreamWriter.drainEncoder (OutputStreamWriter.java:197)
java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close (OutputStreamWriter.java:139)
android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:3385)
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:614)
android.widget.ImageView.<init> (ImageView.java:134)
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:57)
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init> (AppCompatImageView.java:53)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView (LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:691)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:762)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:771)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:771)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:771)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:499)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:398)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:354)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6357592/284308

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra my code is big if you are interested in a specific part tell me

Comment: @Prexx I've seen this answer I'm having the problem when inflating the layout and i'm doing it in the UI thread "As if I could do it in another thread"

Comment: Could you post this code snipped?

Comment: Remove the ImageView from the layout

Comment: @Prexx  I edited the question and added the code

Comment: @cricket_007 I cannot replicate the issue so removing the ImageView will do nothing

Comment: Could you please also add the layout xml?

Comment: The ImageView's drawable is the problem, that's all I can point out... You could try loading it  using Glide, for example

Comment: @Prexx the xml is over 150 line 
the weird thing it works perfectly on almost all api versions and mobiles we have over 100000 user and yet we have that special case

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm using picasso also the crash happens when creating the ImageView not while loading the image to the ImageView

Comment: Your image is loading from the XML, though, during the constructor of the ImageView. `ImageView.<init>`, it seems

Comment: @A.Edwar Then post the ImageView only.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have two ImageViews one for an icon that is loaded from the resources and the other one is loaded later from a server, so you think that the icon is the one causing trouble

Comment: Whichever image is loaded from the XML is having the issue, yes. It may be device independent, but that's just the way of trying to support every device

Comment: @Prexx I edited the question

Comment: @cricket_007 so the only way is to test it on that device

Comment: What ist that drawable? android:src="@drawable/mydrawable" Is it an image or xml resource?

Comment: @Prexx it's an image