# Delphi - accesing non UI units from inside a thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have the following situation.

We develop in DelphiXE.
We are putting the majority of our functions in a DATAMODULE.

function1 (database, transaction, paramInteger) : float

for example 
function1 take parameters database (TIBDATABASE), the transaction TIBTRANSACTIOn and aditiona parameter integer. and return a float

```
function  GetLastPretAch(DIBase : TIBDatabase; Tran : TIBTransaction; const aID : Integer) : Double;
var workQuery : TIBQuery;
begin
  try
    workQuery := TIBQuery.Create(Application);
    try
      workQuery.Close;
      workQuery.Database    := DIBase;
      workQuery.Transaction := Tran;
      workQuery.SQL.Clear;
      workQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM GETLASTPRETACH(-1, :AARTNR)');
      workQuery.ParamByName('AARTNR').AsInteger := aID;
      workQuery.Open;
      Result := workQuery.FieldByName('LASTPRET').AsFloat;
    except
      on e : Exception do begin
        raise EMagisterException.Create(TranslateIbError(e));
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(workQuery);
  end;
end;
```

Now I want to use this functions from a thread. is this thread safe?

```
inside execute procedure like
  ID := GetLastPretAch(database, transaction, 1);
```

is or not thread safe?

Comment: You cannot execute pseudo code. Neither from the main thread, nor a worker thread. If you want to know whether or not some code is threadsafe you need 1. to know what the code is, 2. to know the threading model, and 3. to define [precisely what you mean by threadsafe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx).

Comment: what you mean by pseudo code ? is a regular function USED in the MAIN THREAD...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

Comment: ok you misunderstood the code written. I will write the entire function if you need.

Comment: What makes you think I misunderstood anything? Your original question revision contained pseudo code. I note that the latest update refers to a VCL object (`Application`) in a thread which is not permitted. I'd still like to know what you mean by "thread safe".

Comment: @Popa: I don´t know much about Interbase, but I found a post that may be useful for you: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30131

Comment: thread safe means = zero possibility to get an error from the fact that I use a thread component to access a function from another unit. (non UI)

Comment: What is shared between your threads?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is Yes, you can use that function from inside a worker thread's execute procedure. You might want to consider refining your SQL to only SELECT the field LASTPRET instead of SELECT *.

For an extended discussion on what "thread safe" means refer to this SO question
[What does threadsafe mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033879/what-does-threadsafe-mean)

Comment: It is safe provided that the DB component(s) themselves are thread-safe. For example, ADO is not thread-safe because ADO uses ActiveX internally and has to be accessed in the same thread context that creates those ActiveX objects. If the DataModule were created in a worker thread, then that thread can use ADO components on the DataModule, but the same is not true if the DataModule is created in the main thread instead. Most DB frameworks can be accessed across thread boundaries without synchronizing, but others might not (ADO is the only one that comes to mind right now).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using IBX Components which, the last time I looked were most definitely NOT thread-safe. If you switched to a data access layer that was thread-safe, you should be fine with that code. FYI UIB (Unified Interbase components) are thread-safe.