# Sending a non-threadsafe class (FileBody) to a multithreading container

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x

Apache's `org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody` is @NotThreadSafe. Can I safely pass multiple post requests having such FileBody over the network. A sample would be via `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient` wherein the receiving servlet is a `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`? I'm wondering if the receiving servlet might mix up request contents during FileBody processing by `org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload`.

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
...//execute this multiple times in different jvm's 
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
... //add other entity parts here
FileBody body = new FileBody(new File(file));
entity.add("file", body);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
... //add other post elements here
post.setEntity(entity);
new DefaultHttpClient().execute(post);
```

Also, which part of FileBody can be @NotThreadSafe? I don't see any relevant static method in it.

Comment: I think you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033879/what-does-threadsafe-mean

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis why do you think so? Anyway, some containers process each request on a different thread, so...

Comment: Because you don't seem to understand what thread safety is. You should also read up about what HTTP is and how the transport layer of a network works.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what I know with thread safe is that it ideally runs safely on multithreading environments. could I be missing the definition? If the server in my question is multithreaded, will processing an HttpRequest with a NotThreadSafe component possibly run erroneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of multithreading applies to a single process. Take your client application for example. You create a `FileBody` object in one thread. As a `@NotThreadSafe` class, you could not predict its behavior if it was passed around and used by other threads. **Your server plays no part in this.**

> Also, which part of FileBody can be @NotThreadSafe? I don't see any relevant static method in it.

I'm not sure which version of HttpClient you are using. Version 4.3.5 of the library does not have a `FileBody` type annotated with `@NotThreadSafe`. In any case, there is no relation between thread safety and `static` methods. A type could be thread unsafe and not have any `static` methods.

---

`FileBody` is a container/descriptor for the body of an HTTP request. When the `HttpClient` is ready to send the request, it will get the `InputStream` from the `FileBody` and write its bytes to the underlying TCP socket/connection as the body of the HTTP request. These are just bytes. The HTTP server will receive bytes.

Comment: I'm still quite wondering. I was thinking what about if the request was serialized. Anyway, apache-httpclient does not serialize its HTTP requests, no?

Comment: @bimboxX What do you mean _serialize its HTTP requests_? I added an edit to explain what `FileBody` is used for and how.

Comment: What I meant was that when a client object implements Serializable or something, its states could be passed over to the other side. So, I was confirming if FileBody's bytes will not be affected during the server processing by `org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload`.

Comment: @bimboxX Again, even if it was `Serializable`, which it isn't, thread safety applies to a **single** process. Your client is on one physical machine running in a process. Your server is on one physical machine running in a different process.