# Confused about synchronization and thread safety in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

Actually, I am a bit confused in regards of several explanation from website or blog about synchronization and thread-safe. I've done some research on different class of Core Java Api or Java Framework (Collections). And I've often noticed that some class are synchronize and thread-safe which means, at a time, only one thread can access the code.

But I need some precision:

- A class is synchronize ***so*** its thread-safe?
- Or synchronize and thread-safe have two different meaning?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163445/what-do-the-terms-synchronized-and-thread-safe-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A class is synchronize so its thread-safe ?

A class is not synchronized.  Rather a method, or a block of code is synchronized.

Synchronization (using `synchronized`) is one way to make code thread-safe.  There are other ways.

> Or synchronize and thread-safe have two different meaning ?

Yes. They have different meanings.

---

> And i've often noticed that some class are synchronize and thread-safe which means, at a time, only one thread can access the code.

Actually, if you "noticed" that, you were not paying attention!

With a `synchronized` **method**, only one thread can access the code while holding a given lock; i.e. you get mutual exclusion.  If two threads use *different* locks, then you *won't* get mutual exclusion.

The other thing to note is that merely using `synchronized` does not guarantee thread-safety.  You need to use it in the right way:

- threads need to synchronize on the appropriate objects / locks
- threads need to synchronize in all appropriate code
- if the code entails acquiring multiple locks, the locks need to be acquired in an order that avoids deadlocks.