Android Room crash cannot start a transaction within a transaction
I have a room database in my Android app.  A recent change has resulted in crashes:
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot start a transaction within a transaction (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1])
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:1033)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:321)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:300)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:970)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionNonExclusive(SQLiteDatabase.java:904)
   at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionNonExclusive(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.kt:59)
   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.internalBeginTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:527)
   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:511)
   at myapp.data.dao.DocumentDao_Impl$updatePosition$2.call(DocumentDao_Impl.java:1576)
   at myapp.data.dao.DocumentDao_Impl$updatePosition$2.call(DocumentDao_Impl.java:1566)
   at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:64)
   at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
   at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor.execute$lambda$1$lambda$0(TransactionExecutor.java:36)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

The dao for the call is:
@Query("update document set bookmarkLocation=:position, bookmarkLength=:length where documentId=:documentId")
abstract suspend fun updatePosition(
    documentId: String,
    position: Int,
    length: Int
)

Its not using a transaction.   There's nothing above it that starts a transaction.  There's nothing tricky about the entity.  I don't get it, I've used Room extensively.   Why is this simple update causing an issue?  This is happening in production.  I've don't see it in testing.  In production it's causing crashes for about 1% of my users.

On which coroutine dispatcher does updatePosition run? This may be a concurrency issue.

It feels like a concurrency issue (happening to 1% of my users screams so).  But Room should be handling all that.  For the record, this is getting called from a service and its creating its own scope:
val serviceJob: CompletableJob = SupervisorJob(),
val serviceScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + serviceJob)

This might still be the last one transaction not being ended; maybe not thread-safe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033879

Pretty much all sql commands use a transaction, you might not directly specify a transaction begin and commit but all database read or writes happen in a transaction (https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html). A transaction will automatically be created if there is not one already in effect. So most likely a concurrency issue.

Today, I found an issue, that seems to be root cause.
a update was causing a SQLiteConstraintException.  That was being caught.   In my code, there was no transaction there.   Apparently there is in the room generated code.
Once the SQLiteConstraintException happens, the nested transaction issues happens shortly after.
The SQLiteConstraintException was due to a bug where a value was an empty string, that should have been UUID that's a key in another table.
Once I found a way reproduce the SQLiteConstraintException, the nested transaction issue was reproducible too.  Just fixing SQLiteConstraintException, makes the nested transaction issue non-reproducible.    For good measure, I did put the update that had SQLiteConstraintException into transaction as well.
Now the question is: Why did SQLiteConstraintException leave things in bad state when there was not transaction in my code.

two things I realized after thinking about this some more 1) The code that had the SQLiteConstraintException was put in right around when the original problem started.  2) Caughting  the SQLiteConstraintException was a really bad idea.

Pretending that "its not using a transaction" means, that you haven't read the stack-trace. You'd likely have to use TransactionScope with PooledConnection, in order to avoid this race condition.

A wrapper of SQLiteConnection that belongs to a connection pool
and is safe to use in a coroutine.

These 1% of devices might just have slow storage, which makes the first query take too long - resulting in a non-exclusive transaction not being ended, before starting the next one. This probably could even reproduced with quicker storage, when inserting tons of record-sets and not setting the index-column properly, which would lead to a comparably increased I/O time (from BEGIN TRANSACTION until END TRANSACTION).
Also see: Debug coroutines using IntelliJ IDEA.

The room generated code has transactions, but my code does not.

After making some changes to some of my tests, the tests started reproducing the issue.  It was actually, a different call than I originally thought.
adding @Transaction to the doa entry solved the issue:
so it now looks like:
@Query("UPDATE cursor_position SET cursorPosition = :cursorPosition, cursorLength = :cursorLength WHERE documentId = :documentId")
@Transaction
abstract suspend fun updateCursorPosition(
    documentId: String,
    cursorPosition: Int,
    cursorLength: Int
): Int

