# Why use SQLiteOpenHelper over SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my activity I have for example

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(Preferences.DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR)");
Cursor dbResult = db.rawQuery("SELECT value FROM data", null);
// do sometning with cursors
dbResult.close();
db.close();
```

What's the benefit of using **SQLiteOpenHelper** like

```
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWriteableDatabase();
SQLiteDatabase db_2 = helper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor dbResult = db_2.rawQuery("SELECT value FROM data", null);
// do sometning with cursors
dbResult.close();
helper.close();
```

Class itself

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Preferences.DB_NAME, null, Preferences.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR)";
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

Comment: A downside of using SQLiteOpenHelper: In the emulator, getWriteableDatabase() takes 917 ms to run, whereas openOrCreateDatabase() (created) takes 7 ms. This same extreme delay is up to 3000 ms on a physical device and I have found no way around it. I'd rather write my own upgrading code, thank you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

> SQLiteDatabase has methods to create, delete, execute SQL commands,
>   and perform other common database management tasks.

[SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

> A helper class to manage database creation and version management.

I will say this much, the onUpgrade that comes with SQLiteOpenHelper comes in REALLY handy when upgrading your application. It's mainly for creation and upgrading / version management. SQLiteDatabase is mainly for CRUD operations (you can create with it but that is what SQLiteOpenHelper is for).

Comment: What Jack is said is correct. Keep in mind `SQLiteOpenHelper` actually invokes the static methods from `SQLiteDatabase` class.

Answer (score 12):

SQLiteOpenHelper provides utilities to simplify the tasks of creating and initialising the database if it's not already created and converting the contents of the database when your application is upgrading and the database schema changes.

If you have a very simple database schema, then it doesn't really get you much, but for anything complicated it's a definite help. It makes sure that all the fiddly edge conditions are covered so that you don't have to, such as putting transactions in all the right places to avoid database corruption.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with ..."putting transactions...". After looking at the source code there's not much additional work in the helper class. It checks for existance, creates or opens the database, checks the version and calls onCreate/onUpdate. Building transactions around your statements is still up to you if you use the SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 5):

Above of other answers, one very important feature in `SQLiteOpenHelper` class, it has 2 synchronized methods, `getWritableDatabase()` and `getReadableDatabase()`.

That means your database operations are [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261683/what-is-meant-by-thread-safe-code?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Code snippet from `SQLiteOpenHelper` class

```
public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
    synchronized (this) {
        return getDatabaseLocked(false);
    }
}
```

and

```
public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    synchronized (this) {
        return getDatabaseLocked(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is written in the official developer reference

> A helper class to manage database creation and version management.
>
> You create a subclass implementing onCreate(SQLiteDatabase),
>   onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and optionally
>   onOpen(SQLiteDatabase), and this class takes care of opening the
>   database if it exists, creating it if it does not, and upgrading it as
>   necessary. Transactions are used to make sure the database is always
>   in a sensible state.
>
> This class makes it easy for ContentProvider implementations to defer
>   opening and upgrading the database until first use, to avoid blocking
>   application startup with long-running database upgrades.
>
> For an example, see the NotePadProvider class in the NotePad sample
>   application, in the samples/ directory of the SDK.

So SQLiteOpenHelper make things pretty easier.

You can use this link to learn how to handle SQLite with SQLiteOpenHelper. **[SQLiteOpenHelper Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/sqliteopenhelper-tutorial/)**.