# Activity and Background Service Access to SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, android-service, android-sqlite

I want to check if a SQLite Database is open, and if it is, I would like to access that Database within a service class.

I am worried, and have seen, that multiple open calls to the database clash, and throw exceptions. Because I do query the database within both my Activity and Service classes, I am attempting to implement the solution Commonsware recommended here: [When to close db connection on android? Every time after your operation finished or after your app exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842112/when-to-close-db-connection-on-android-every-time-after-your-operation-finished/4842251#4842251). However I do not want to close then open the Database within the Service class if the Activity might need it. From this answer [Why use SQLiteOpenHelper over SQLiteDatabase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058267/why-use-sqliteopenhelper-over-sqlitedatabase), it looks like it might make sense to implement a SQLiteOpenHelper to solve the issue of making multiple calls.

Thank you so much for all your help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This man Kevin is a legend: http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection. Thank you so much.

On that link he shares his ridiculously simple solution:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
private static DatabaseHelper instance;

    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getHelper(Context context)
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        return instance;
    }
    //Other stuff... 
}
```

Then in my SQLite class I changed my code to look like this:

```
public BlacklistWordDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = MySQLiteHelper.getHelper(context);
}
```

Comment: It's just a singleton code, why to be so fascinated about it?

Comment: A true legend doesn't worry about his (or her) critics.  Anyway, the legend continues: http://kpgalligan.tumblr.com/post/109546839958/single-database-connection.  Its just a collection of links on the topic.  It keeps coming up.

Answer (score -2):

at onCreat in the activity put datasource.open();
then do what ever you want
and at the end of actevity put this to close :

```
  /** Call after close activity */
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //Close dataSource
    datasource.close();
}
```