# Difference between openOrCreateDatabase of SQLiteDatabase and Context?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context

Android has `openOrCreateDatabase`s in two different classes: [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.io.File,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)) and [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)). May I ask what are the differences between them?

Meanwhile, I am using a singleton class for maintaining my database. If I want to use that one database across many activities, which version of `openOrCreateDatabase` will be more suitable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058267/why-use-sqliteopenhelper-over-sqlitedatabase I think This is Similiar question

Comment: @TominB no? This question is about the differences between a method with the same name (that in theory should do the same thing) in two completely different classes, not SQLiteHelper...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use SQLiteOpenHelper over SQLiteDatabase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058267/why-use-sqliteopenhelper-over-sqlitedatabase)

Comment: @HadjKhelilNawrez No. SQLiteOpenHelper is not even mentioned in this question. As Zoe commented above, this question is about two methods with a same name under different classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your question about the difference between `Context.openOrCreateDatabase` and `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase` the answer lies withing this sentence:

> Open a new private SQLiteDatabase associated with this Context's
>   application package.

`Context.openOrCreateDatabase` creates the database file which is located in the application's private data folder whereas `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase` can create the database anywhere your app has write access to.

As for your second question I think it matters not which one you choose to use.

Comment: For what it's worth, `ContextImpl` uses `SQLiteDatabase` internally.