# Windows Thread Synchronization with create semaphore

Tags: multithreading, wait, semaphore

I am trying on a problem with writer and reader. I am trying with windows semaphore functionality.

It is very simple as follows

```
      char n[200];
      volatile HANDLE hSem=NULL; // handle to semaphore
```

The write function for console. Which release the semaphore for the read process.

```
     void * write_message_function ( void *ptr )
      {


      /* do the work */
      while(1){
            printf("Enter a string");
            scanf("%s",n);

            ReleaseSemaphore(hSem,1,NULL); // unblock all the threads
        }

      pthread_exit(0); /* exit */
      }
```

The print message wait for the release from the write message to print the message.

```
      void * print_message_function ( void *ptr )
      {


       while(1){
            WaitForSingleObject(hSem,INFINITE);
            printf("The string entered is :");
            printf("==== %s\n",n);

         }

       pthread_exit(0); /* exit */
      }
```

The main function launch the application.

```
     int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {

     hSem=CreateSemaphore(NULL,0,1,NULL);
     pthread_t thread1, thread2;  /* thread variables */
     /* create threads 1 and 2 */    
     pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, print_message_function, NULL);
     pthread_create (&thread2, NULL, write_message_function, NULL);

     pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
     pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

     /* exit */  
     CloseHandle(hSem); 

     }
```

The program executes but does not show the string input console.

Answer (score 0):

`ReleaseSemaphore` in `write_message_function` will force the following:

1. The `print_message_function` will start the output **and**
2. The `write_message_function` will output and scan for input.

These two things occur *at the same time*. Using the semaphore to trigger the output is
fine. However, using `MaximumCount=1` is a waste of capabilities, you may have mutiple inputs before an output occurs.
But the main problem here is that the I/O resources and the use of `char n[200];` are not
implemented thread-safe. See [What is meant by “thread-safe” code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261683/what-is-meant-by-thread-safe-code) for details. You'd still have to protect these resources by for example a `mutex` or a `critical section`.