# Wrong result when running code in parallel

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran, hpc

The `gfortran` compiler gives wrong answer, when I run a parallel program using OpenMP. In the same time, `ifort` gives exact result.

This is the whole compilable code.

```
!_______________________________________________________________ !
!____________MODULE SECTION_____________________________________ !

  MODULE MATRIC
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER , PARAMETER :: NG = 40  
    DOUBLE PRECISION,SAVE :: Z , PA , PB ,CMU 
    DOUBLE PRECISION , PARAMETER :: PI=2.0D0*ACOS(0.0D0) , &
             FPI=4.0D0*PI , SQFPI = SQRT(FPI), DLAM=1.0D0
    DOUBLE PRECISION , DIMENSION(450) :: DEL1,  DEL2, X,  R ,  SNLO 
    DOUBLE PRECISION :: XG(60) , WG(60) 
  END MODULE MATRIC
!_________________________________________________________________________!
!                  MODULE SECTION 
!__________________________________________________________________________!

  MODULE POTDATA
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER                            :: IA , IB , ID       
    DOUBLE PRECISION                   :: RA , RB , R1s(450)     
  END MODULE POTDATA
!__________________________________________________________________________!



!______________________________________________________________________!

  program check
    use matric
    use potdata
    implicit double precision(a-h,o-z)

    pa   = 0.72D0  ;  pb   =  0.19D0  
    mesh = 441     ;  noint=  40      ;  z   =  2.0d0    
    CALL GAULEG(-1.d0,1.d0)

    NB = MESH/NOINT
    I = 1
    X(I) = 0.0D+00
    DELTAX = 0.0025D+00*40.0D+00/DBLE(NOINT)
    DO  J=1,NB
      IMK = (J-1)*NOINT + 1
      DO K=1,NOINT
        AK=K
        I=I+1
        X(I)=X(IMK)+AK*DELTAX
      END DO
      DELTAX=2.0D+00*DELTAX
    END DO

    CMU=(9.0D00*PI*PI/(128.0D00*Z))**THIRD

    R(1)=0.0D+00 ;  SNLO(1) = 0.D00
    DO  I=2,MESH
      R(I)=CMU*X(I)
      SNLO(I) = R(I)*dexp(-Z*R(I))
      R1S(I) = SNLO(I)/(SQFPI*R(I))
    END DO

    call EFFPOT(MESH,NOINT)

  end program check


  subroutine EFFPOT(MESH,NOINT)
    USE OMP_LIB
    USE MATRIC  
    USE POTDATA 
    implicit none 
    integer, intent(in) :: MESH, NOINT 
    double precision::anorm(450)
    double precision, external :: funct
    double precision :: asum, fac, cnorm

!$omp parallel do default(none) private(del1,ia,asum,ib,ra,rb,fac) &
!$omp shared(id,mesh,r,anorm,NOINT,del2,R1s)
    do  ia = 2,mesh
      ra = r(ia)
      if(R1s(ia).lt.1.D-7.and.R1s(ia).ge.1.D-8)id = ia
      do ib = 2,mesh
         rb = r(ib)
         call QGAUSS(funct,-1.d0,1.d0,fac)
         del1(ib) = rb**2*fac*R1s(ib)**2
      end do
      CALL NCDF(del1,ASUM,r(2),mesh,NOINT)
      anorm(ia) = 2.0d0*pi*asum
      del2(ia)  = 2.0d0*pi*asum*(ra*R1s(ia))**2
    end do
!$omp end parallel do

    CALL NCDF(del2,ASUM,r(2),mesh,NOINT)
    cnorm = 1.0/dsqrt(4.*pi*ASUM)
    write(6,*)'cnorm =',cnorm

    return 
  end


  double precision function funct(x)

    USE POTDATA , ONLY : RA , RB 
    USE MATRIC  , ONLY : PA , PB  , DLAM

    implicit none
    double precision, intent(in) :: x
    double precision             :: f1, f2, ramrb

    ramrb = dsqrt(ra**2+rb**2-2.d0*ra*rb*x)
    f1 = dcosh(pa*ra)+dcosh(pa*rb)
    f2  = 1.d0+0.5*dlam*ramrb*dexp(-pb*ramrb)
    funct = (f1*f2)**2
    return
  end


  SUBROUTINE QGAUSS(func,aa,bb,ss)
    USE OMP_LIB
    USE MATRIC , ONLY : XG ,WG , NG 
    IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION(A-H,O-Z)
    external func
    xm = 0.5d0*(bb+aa)
    xl = 0.5d0*(bb-aa)
    ss = 0.d0
    do  j=1,ng
      dx = xl*xg(j)
      ss = ss + wg(j)*(func(xm+dx)+func(xm-dx))
    end do
    ss = xl*ss/2.0
    return
  END


  SUBROUTINE GAULEG(x1,x2)

    USE MATRIC , ONLY : XG ,WG ,NG , PI

    IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION(A-H,O-Z)
    eps = 1.d-14
    m = (ng+1)/2
    xm = 0.5D0*(x1+x2)
    xl = 0.5D0*(x2-x1)

    do i=1,m
      z = dcos(pi*(dfloat(i)-0.25d0)/(dfloat(ng)+0.5d0))
1     continue
      p1 = 1.d0
      p2 = 0.d0

      do j=1,ng
        p3 = p2
        p2 = p1
        p1 = ((2.d0*dfloat(j)-1.d0)*z*p2  &
          - (dfloat(j)-1.d0)*p3)/dfloat(j)
      end do

      pp = dfloat(ng)*(z*p1-p2)/(z*z-1.d0)
      z1 = z
      z = z1 - p1/pp
      if (dabs(z-z1).gt.eps) go to 1
      xg(i) = xm - xl*z
      xg(ng+1-i) = xm + xl*z
      wg(i) = 2.d0*xl/((1.d0-z*z)*pp*pp)
      wg(ng+1-i) = wg(i)                          
    end do
    return
  end


  SUBROUTINE NCDF(F,ASUM,H,KKK,NOINT)
    IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
    DIMENSION F(450)
    NBLOCK = (KKK-2)/NOINT + 1
    C2HO45 = 2.0D+00*H/45.0D+00      
    ASUM = 0.0D+00

    DO  J=1,NBLOCK
      ISTAR = NOINT*(J-1)+5
      IEND = NOINT*J + 1
      IEND = MIN0(KKK,IEND)
      DO  I=ISTAR,IEND,4
          ASUM = ASUM + C2HO45*(7.0D+00*(F(I-4)+F(I))  &
                +32.0D+00*(F(I-3)+F(I-1)) + 12.0D+00*F(I-2))
      END DO
      IF(IEND.EQ.KKK) GO TO 4
      C2HO45 = 2.0D+00*C2HO45
4   END DO

    RETURN
  END
```

Thanks everybody specially @Vladimir who has taken interest in my problem. Finally i got the right answer by removing ra and rb from the module potdata and defined function as funct(x, ra, rb) and then removing ra and rb from the loop. Because i was writing ra, rb then reading their values in the above code so loop was having flow dependence. Now i get exact result from both compiler (which is 8.7933767516) parallelly, sequentially both. Exact way is this

```
subroutine EFFPOT(MESH,NOINT)
    USE OMP_LIB
    USE MATRIC  
    USE POTDATA 
  implicit none 
  integer, intent(in) :: MESH, NOINT 
  double precision::anorm(450)
  double precision, external :: funct
  double precision :: asum, fac, cnorm
 !$omp parallel do default(none) private(del1,ia,asum,ib,fac) &
 !$omp shared(id,mesh,r,anorm,NOINT,del2,R1s)

  do  ia = 2,mesh
      if(R1s(ia).lt.1.D-7.and.R1s(ia).ge.1.D-8)id = ia
      do ib = 2,mesh
         call QGAUSS(funct,-1.d0,1.d0,fac,r(ia),r(ib))
         del1(ib) = r(ib)**2*fac*R1s(ib)**2
      end do
      CALL NCDF(del1,ASUM,r(2),mesh,NOINT)
      anorm(ia) = 2.0d0*pi*asum
      del2(ia)  = 2.0d0*pi*asum*(r(ia)*R1s(ia))**2
  end do

 !$omp end parallel do
  CALL NCDF(del2,ASUM,r(2),mesh,NOINT)
  cnorm = 1.0/dsqrt(4.*pi*ASUM)
  write(6,*)'cnorm =',cnorm

  return 
  end


      double precision function funct(x,ra,rb)
      USE MATRIC  , ONLY : PA , PB  , DLAM

      implicit none
      double precision, intent(in) :: x, ra, rb
      double precision             :: f1, f2, ramrb

      ramrb = dsqrt(ra**2+rb**2-2.d0*ra*rb*x)
      f1 = dcosh(pa*ra)+dcosh(pa*rb)
      f2  = 1.d0+0.5*dlam*ramrb*dexp(-pb*ramrb)
      funct = (f1*f2)**2
  return
  end
  SUBROUTINE QGAUSS(func,aa,bb,ss,ra,rb)
     USE OMP_LIB
     USE MATRIC , ONLY : XG ,WG , NG 
     IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION(A-H,O-Z)
     external func
     xm = 0.5d0*(bb+aa)
     xl = 0.5d0*(bb-aa)
     ss = 0.d0
   do  j=1,ng
     dx = xl*xg(j)
     ss = ss + wg(j)*(func(xm+dx,ra,rb)+func(xm-dx,ra,rb))
   end do
   ss = xl*ss/2.0
   return
  END
```

Comment: Please show us some code!

Comment: In the  part of the code above,  MESH,  NOINT, R1s, R ,ra,rb,are taken from a module.NCDF and QGAUSS are integration subroutine.

Comment: How different are the values of `cnorm`?

Comment: It would be useful to see the signatures of the functions NCDF and QGAUSS, too.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: del1 is declared private and therefore not a problem

Comment: Are you sure that NCDF and QGAUSS are thread-safe? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261683/what-is-meant-by-thread-safe-code

Comment: Thanks@Vladimir F,  QGAUSS does not use any variable which is common with subroutine having the above part of the code so i think it should be completly independent and because ra, rb are private so values of funct should not create problem. NCDF only reads the variables mesh and noint and  del1 is private so no problem i think.

Comment: @rabeetsingh That is not enough, you must be sure that all procedures are compiled with openMP enabled or as recursive, otherwise anything can happen.

Comment: @Vladimir, okk thank you  i am trying..with -debug option ifort also gives 15.9999.

Comment: Did you try the Intel Inspector? If you want ua to help you in any way you must provide complete compilable example as simplified as possible.

Comment: @Vladimir, Its not available in the  cluster. I talked to upload it on the cluster. So it will take some time.  Can you please tell me that how much cost it will take if i install it on my PC for fortran.

Comment: Try some other things first. Isolate the problem. Get rid of everything unrelated and create a small compilable program that reproduces the issue. Then we can have a look.

Comment: Okk, thank you. i will do.

Comment: @Vladimir, I have seprated the problematic part from the original program but its still 200 lines because i have to include three more subroutines at least qgauss, ncdf, gauleg ( to produce weight and abscissae).

Comment: One more thing i noticed is the flow dependence that is writing ra, rb then reading their values.

Comment: Then include the 200 lines.

Comment: Updated the question with whole program

Comment: Now we don't see what is the wrong result and what is the right result. It should be there so we know what to look for.

Comment: Thanks friend@Vladimir.  Problem is solved now.  Shared the way above. Right answer 8.7933767516(sequentially) and wrong answer  15.999999998978822 parallely with gfortran.

Answer (score 4):

The cause of your problem is that the OpenMP standard does not specify what happens if a `private` list item is accessed in the region but outside of the construct. See example [`private.2f`](http://openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-examples-4.0.2.pdf) (found on page 135 of the OpenMP standard supplement) for a short version of the same problem.

Specifically, the module variables `ra` and `rb` are declared `private` in the OpenMP parallel region inside `EFFPOT` and also accessed from `funct`. `funct` is in the dynamic scope of the parallel region but (lexically) outside of it and therefore it is not specified whether `ra` and `rb` referenced by `funct` are the original module variables or their private copies (most compilers would go for the original variables).

You have already found one of the solutions. The other one would be to declare `ra` and `rb` `threadprivate` since they are only used to pass data from `EFFPOT` to `funct`:

```
MODULE POTDATA
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER                            :: IA , IB , ID       
  DOUBLE PRECISION                   :: RA , RB , R1s(450)
  !$OMP THREADPRIVATE(RA,RB)
END MODULE POTDATA
```

You should then also remove `ra` and `rb` from the list of the `private` clause of the parallel region within `EFFPOT`.

On some platforms, e.g. OS X, using `threadprivate` with GCC (i.e. `gfortran`) could be slower than actually passing around the two variables as arguments because of the emulated TLS.

Note that this semantic error is really hard to detect and many OpenMP tools won't actually spot it.

Comment: Thanks@Hristo IIiev, I will try your solutions also.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is very difficult to say something specific without seeing the actual code. However, I do have some comments on your situation and the conclusions you are drawing.

The fact that your program runs fine both in parallel and sequential execution when compiled with "ifort" doesn't mean that your program is correct. Since compiler bugs leading to programs giving wrong answers are very rare, but on the other hand manual parallel programming is very error-prone, we should assume a problem with the way you parallelized your code. We are probably talking about a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

And no, the problem you are having is not at all unusual. When you have a race condition, it happens often that the sequential execution works everywhere and your parallel execution works in some environments and fails in others. It's even common that your code gives different answers every time you call it (not only depending on the compiler, but on many other factors that can change over time).

What I suggest you should do, is to get a parallel debugger, like for example [TotalView](http://www.roguewave.com/products-services/totalview) that will help you keep track of the various threads and their states. Try to find a simple test environment (as few threads as possible) that fails reliably.

Comment: Thanks for giving your time.  Thanks for stack overflow also.

Comment: @rabeetsingh With ifort you can use https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inspector-xe to identify problematic spots in the code.