# Creating an operator that can access the unique ID of an instance of class

Tags: c++, class, operators, constants

I want to create an unique id for each instance of a class, that cannot be modified.
Then I want to create an operator `==` such that `p1==p2` returns `true` if p1 and p2 have the same id, i.e. are the same element.
The way I plan to do it is:

*parent.hpp*

```
class parent{
    public:
        ...
        int parent::GetUid() const;

    private:
        static int newUID;
        const int uid;

}
```

*parent.cpp*

```
bool operator ==(const parent p1, const parent p2)
{
    return (p1.GetUid()== p2.GetUid());
}

parent::parent()
:uid(newUID++){}


int parent::newUID=0;

int parent::GetUid() const
    {
        return uid;
    }
```

But though I do initialize `newUID`, I get the following error:

> error c2789 an object of const-qualified type must be initialized

**EDIT**: the above error is solved and occurred because of a typo I made.

Now when I try to use the operator I get the following error:

> error C2676: binary '==' : 'parent' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

I get this error when I do the following:

```
parent p1;
parent p2;
...
if(p1==p2){
    t=0;
}
```

Comment: `iuid(newUID++)` -> `uid(newUID++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should at least compile if you write `parent::parent() :uid(newUID++){}`. Note, however, that you have to do some more work to tackle the idea of "identity" that way. First, `newUID++` is not thread safe, so you could create different object with the same "identity". Then, you have to provide a copy constructor unless you want to allow that the same "identity" may be represented by different objects in memory.

Comment: Thank you for the typo. What do you mean by "trade safe" ? Indeed, I did not think about the copy constructor, thanks.

Comment: @Arthurim  I don't see the phrase "trade safe" anywhere in the answer, can you elaborate on what you are asking about? I can see "thread safe" in the answer, and thread safety is whole other topic: [What is meant by “thread-safe” code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261683/what-is-meant-by-thread-safe-code).

Comment: `newUID++` is not an atomic operation; it consists of "read the value of  `newUID`" and "increment the value of `newUID`". When two threads create  `parent`-objects concurrently, both threads might both perform the "reading"-part before the other has reached the  "incrementing"-part, respectively.  So two threads might assign the same `uid`. That's why it is not thread-safe. Use a `mutex` or `std::atomic`. Of course - thread-safety only  matters if you are  in  a  multithreaded environment, i.e. if your program spawns multiple threads....

Comment: Mea Culpa, I meant to write "thread" and not "trade". Thank you, I understand this better. I am not doing any multithreading here and the user won't be neither. However, I still have a compiler error when using the operator, see my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the address of each parent ?

```
bool operator == (const parent &p1, const parent &p2)
{
    return &p1 == &p2;
}
```

Comment: Would not preserve the ID through moves or or storage in most library containers.

Comment: That's not a part of the problem description.  He stated that each instance has a unique ID.

Comment: Have to disagree with that read of intent. If I had an object with a known identifier I would not expect or want that identifier to change because another object was removed from a `vector`. You can't count on it as an identifier anymore.

Comment: @user4581301
You're assuming that he will keep the instances in a container, *and* keep pointers to individual elements ?