# is below class thread safe ? explain

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Can someone explain whether or not I can call the below class "**thread safe**"?

As far as I know, we can call something thread safe if we are not breaking *existing functionality*

Example:

```
public class BackgroundWorker
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, RunningTask> _runningTasks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, RunningTask>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes async job for the specified key, only one at a time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    public void Enqueue(string key)
    {
        if (_runningTasks.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _runningTasks[key].Repeat = true;
            return;
        }

        _runningTasks[key] = new RunningTask();

        ExecuteTask(key);
    }

    private void ExecuteTask(string key)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Do something

            if (_runningTasks[key].Repeat)
            {
                _runningTasks[key].Repeat = false;
                ExecuteTask(key);
                return;
            }

            _runningTasks.Remove(key);
        });
    }

    private class RunningTask
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Flag to repeat a task after completion.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Repeat { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please format the code blocks with this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Being thread safe has nothing to do with "breaking existing functionality"

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so because `_runningTasks` is shared object and your method `Enqueue` is writing on this shared object. For example its possible when one thread already executed line number y, another thread will evaluate condition check in line number x as true - which might not be intention.

```
public void Enqueue(string key)
{
    if (_runningTasks.ContainsKey(key)) /*say line no : x */
    {
        _runningTasks[key].Repeat = true;
        return;
    }

    _runningTasks[key] = new RunningTask(); /*say line no:y*/

    ExecuteTask(key);
}
```

Using `ConcurrentDictionary` will just ensure no two threads can read/write to/from the dictionary same time.

To your second point :

> As far as I know, we can call something thread safe if we are not
>   breaking existing functionality

No this is not the definition of thread safe (might be ok to say one of desirable outcome in multi threaded environment) I would recommend to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261683/what-is-meant-by-thread-safe-code) for official meaning rather.

Comment: Just to clarify: A `ConcurrentDictionary` does not make the class thread-safe. Still, a thread may be preempted between line x and line `_runningTasks[key].Repeat = true;` and another thread may remove the task from the dictionary. Hence, the second line may throw a `KeyNotFoundException`.

Comment: Doesn't ConcurrentDictionary have an [`AddOrUpdate` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378665.aspx)?