# multiprocessing.Pipe() vs .Queue()

Tags: python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocess as mp
```

What are the key differences between `mp.Pipe()` and `mp.Queue()`? They seem to be the same to me: basically `Pipe.recv()` is equivalent to `Queue.get()`, and `Pipe.send()` is `Queue.put()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're very different things, with very different behavior.

A [`Queue` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) has `put`, `get`, `empty`, `full`, and various other methods.  It has an optional maximum size (number of items, really).  Anyone can put or get into any queue.  It is process-safe as it handles all the locking.

The [`Pipe` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe)—note that this is a function, not a class instance—returns two objects of type [`Connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection) (these are the class instances).  These two instances are connected to each other.  The connection between them can be single-duplex, i.e., you can only send on one and only receive on the other, or it can be full-duplex, i.e., whatever you actually send on one is received on the other.  The two objects have `send`, `recv`, `send_bytes,` `recv_bytes`, `fileno`, and `close` methods among others.  The send and receive methods use the pickling code to translate between objects and bytes since the actual data transfer is via byte-stream.  The connection objects are *not* locked and therefore *not* process-safe.

Data transfer between processes generally uses these `Connection` objects: this and shared-memory are the underlying mechanism for all process-to-process communication in the multiprocessing code.  `Queue` instances are much higher level objects, which ultimately need to use a `Connection` to send or receive the byte-stream that represents the object being transferred across the queue.  So in that sense, they do the same thing—but that's a bit like saying that a USB cable does the same thing as the things that connect them.  Usually, you don't want to deal with individual voltages on a wire: it's much nicer to just send or receve a whole object.  (This analogy is a little weak, because `Connection` instances have `send` and `recv` as well as `send_bytes` and `recv_bytes`, but it's probably still helpful.)

Comment: Thanks! Could you expand on *process-safe* or point me to a good introductory link to this concept? I couldn't find any giving me a full picture, so far I only know it's has something to do with locking.

Comment: "Process-safe" is the process variant of "thread-safe". Since processes are largely walled off from each other (except for shared memory if you use it—shared memory opens up all the thread issues), this comes down to the fact that operations on a shared file descriptor, such as the two in a Pipe value pair, affect another process's operations on the same shared file descriptor. For thread safety—a much bigger issue—see https://stackoverflow.com/q/261683/1256452.

Comment: As a sort of overgeneralization, if you make a half-duplex Pipe between processes A and B, and just send from A to B, or a full-duplex Pipe and make sure that there's never a case where B tries to send to A *while* A is sending to B or vice versa, and that you don't have some third process C also send to B while A is sending to B, you're pretty safe.